# Springboot profiles

Tags: spring-boot

This is my jenkins file where I am building the Spring boot application. How do I pass my spring boot profile like `application-dev.properties` in the below code. So it can pick up the profile and build the jar.

Please help. Thanks in advance.

```
stage('Build application') {
            steps {
                sh 'mvn clean package'

            }
        }
```

Comment: You wouldn't set the profile at build time.

Comment: Spring profiles are runtime, which typically means you inject them via a startup parameter when the application is started.

Comment: Thank you. That's a quick help. Is there any other way to do it?

Comment: I without knowing exactly how your application is set up, I can only speculate. But one solution is to use the `SpringApplicationBuilder` if you start the app from a `main`-method, and then pass a profile there: https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/api/org/springframework/boot/builder/SpringApplicationBuilder.html#profiles-java.lang.String...-

Comment: The power of Spring Boot's profile as that you can run the same the application with different profiles, is there a reason why you want to it otherwise. What is the question behind your question, do you want to know how pass a profile when running the app?

Comment: I want to create spring boot profiles like application-dev,application-prod.propeties and pass one of them while building the jar. So the application can pick up the profile which I have passed while building. This can be achieved using maven, so checking on that. Thank you in advance.

Comment: We are able to achieve this using below code:                                  
        stage('Build application') {
            steps {
                sh "mvn clean package -P ${params.NAME_PREFIX}"
              
            }